# Binding a DataGridView to multiple Tables in DataViewManager or DataSet

Tags: datagridview, binding, dataset, dataviewmanager

I have created three data tables by pulling data from an sql database.   DT1, DT2, DT3.
  I have added these three tables to a data set, myDS. 
 I have added relations between these three tables.
 I then dragged a DataGridView onto my form and I want to bind the three tables to the DataGridview.  So I added my dataset DS to a dataview manager, myDVM.  I bound myDVM to a bindingsource, bindingSource1, and made it the data source for the DataGridView. 
 I am not sure how to bind the tables I want from myDVM / bindingSource1,  to appear in the DataGridView.
i want to display the child tables related to the parent table using primary key in the same datagridview!!

thanks in advance!!!

help me plz!!!

Answer (score 1):

If by "display the child tables" you mean display related data from child tables, you should SELECT your data into a single table using the appropriate joins.  DataGridViews display their data in a single-table format - there is no "multiple table" concept in a DataGridView.

[DataSet.Merge()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge.aspx) can help you to merge DataRows from separate objects into one.

Comment: can we append these three tables using merge() ?

bcoz, these tables may contain different columnname... 

how that will work???

 explain with an example!

thanks for ur quick response, andy!

Comment: Did you visit the link?  If you do, you will see that there is an overload that handles incompatible schemas.

Comment: Examples can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszytsd8.aspx