# how to Binding DataGridView to multiple Tables in DataViewManager

Tags: datagridview

i have two tables 'customer' and 'Location'
these tabls have relation 
i just want to dispaly these tables ina datagrid view like parent and child tables(which is expandable one(+ like) when i click the + button it will display the child one in the same datagrid view

pls help me....

thanks...

Comment: thanks for ur replay but ..
does it possible to show two append tables in one datagrid view?


pls replay

Answer (score 1):

This was asked [45 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830761/binding-a-datagridview-to-multiple-tables-in-dataviewmanager-or-dataset).

**EDIT**: On further inspection, I see that the questions are slightly different.  This one mentions expandable rows.  But the titles are almost identical.

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1098858/2716090.aspx

And another:

http://www.progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=54

Comment: thanks , really u r great ......
i want the same example wich i want to do these in windows form ....
plsssssssssssss.....


thank u